# libanpr non-documented library for vehicle plate recognition

Tags: image-processing, automatic-license-plate-recognition

Has anyone here dealt with [libanpr](http://sourceforge.net/p/libanpr/code/HEAD/tree/)?
it's a library for automatic vehicle plate recognition.
I tried to compile it, but I had a lot of errors that I can't resolve them. I don't find even one page of documentation!
can some one help?

Edited:

**Solution.**

I could not compile it under Linux,  but under windows I did. 
Now my problem is that there are neither documentations nor discussion about this library!. I tried the next code, but upon execution it crashes, where when I debug (step by step), the code works, but I can't work with this way to get the results.
I can't manipulate over the code because we have no idea about any class or any function!!

Is there someone interested to share me to find a solution ??

```
#include "../source/AvcodecImgSrc.h"
#include "../locate/CarLocate.h"
#include "../plate/PlateCut.h"
#include "../ocr/PlateOcr.h"
#include "../exception/Exception.h"

static void show(const std::vector<OcrData>& plates) {
for (int i=0;i<plates.size();i++)
printf("%s\n", plates[i].getPlate().c_str());
```

}

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
      try {
         AvcodecImgSrc src(argv[1], 400, 3450);
         CarLocate car(2048/4, 1536/4, 8, 5);
         PlateCut plate;
    PlateOcr ocr;
    while (src.hasNext()) {
      NTCImg img = src.next();
      int w = img.dimx();
      int h = img.dimy();
      int w2 = w/2;
      int h2 = h/2;
      NTCImg img2 = img.getScale(w2, h2);
      int w4 = w/4;
      int h4 = h/4;
      NTCImg img4g = img.getScaleG(w4, h4);
      std::vector<CarData> cars = car.locate(img4g);
      for (int i=0;i<cars.size();i++) {
        printf("CAR[%dx%d]!\n", cars[i].getRect().getWidth(), cars[i].getRect().getHeight());
      }
      std::vector<PlateData> plates = plate.cut(img2, CarData::scale2(cars));
      for (int i=0;i<plates.size();i++) {
        printf("PLATE[%dx%d]!\n", plates[i].getRect().getWidth(), plates[i].getRect().getHeight());
      }
      //show(ocr.run(plate.cut(cars)));
    }
  } catch (const Exception& ex) {
    printf("Exception: %s\n", ex.getMsg().c_str());
  } catch (const Err& err) {
    printf("Err!\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: This lib is 3 years old?

Comment: Yeh, but updated since 2013-04-19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a waste of time!
this library is not complete, I could compile it, after a tough debugging, OCR, the very important part, is removed !! 
I don't suggest anybody to loose his energy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out OpenALPR (http://www.openalpr.com).  It is a complete, open source license plate recognition library written in C++.  The compile is also fairly simple.